# How to use a multiarch base docker image when specifying SHA

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sha

I'm stuck following our internal procedure that *requires* pinning a docker base image to a specific SHA. *And*, I'm stuck needing to build a mulitarch image for both x86_64 and ARM.

The base image that [I'm looking at](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/minideb/tags) has a SHA for each architecture (which I would expect, makes total sense). So how can I specify a *specific* SHA in the `FROM` if the *resulting* image is also supposed to be multiarch? Am I stuck using a `Dockerfile` for each arch??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Docker Hub now shows the digest for the multi-platform index, so you can use that, or one of the tools listed below to get that digest:

[image: Docker Hub screenshot of a tag including the index digest]

---

The manifest list for a multi-platform image has its own digest, and that is what you want to provide to tools. There are a variety of tools that can get this. My own tool is regclient with the regctl CLI, go-containerregistry from Google has crane, and Docker has been including an imagetools CLI under buildx:

```bash
$ regctl image digest bitnami/minideb
sha256:713d1fbd2edbc7adf0959721ad360400cb39d6b680057f0b50599cba3a4db09f

$ crane digest bitnami/minideb
sha256:713d1fbd2edbc7adf0959721ad360400cb39d6b680057f0b50599cba3a4db09f

$ docker buildx imagetools inspect bitnami/minideb
Name:      docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest
MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:    sha256:713d1fbd2edbc7adf0959721ad360400cb39d6b680057f0b50599cba3a4db09f
           
Manifests: 
  Name:      docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest@sha256:2abaa4a8ba2c3ec9ec3cb16a55820db8d968919f41439e1e8c86faca81c8674a
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64
             
  Name:      docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest@sha256:3c44390903734b2657728fcad8fb33dcdf311bdeaafcc3b9f179d78bdf4da669
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm64
```